# Subversion post-commit with different user

Tags: linux, svn

I've installed subversion and have the following setup:

- The repo is **/home/svn/tester** (**apache:apache**).
- The site is **/var/www/tester** (**tester:tester**).

I've checked out the tester repo to **/var/www/tester**.

In **/home/svn/tester/hooks/post-commit** I have:

```
sudo -u tester /usr/bin/svn update /home/tester --username aaa --password bbb
```

What I am trying to do is keep the owner of the files in **/home/svn/tester** as **apache** and the owner of the files in **/var/www/tester** as **tester**.

I have added to /etc/sudoers:

```
tester ALL=(ALL) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/svn
```

I've commented out requiretty in /etc/sudoers:

```
#Defaults    requiretty
```

Once I run the commit I receive the following message (in tortoisesvn):

```
Commit failed (details follow):
MERGE of '/svn/tester': 200 OK (https://[site name])
```

Am I going about this the correct way? If so how can I get passed this error?

Comment: This question is more suited for 

http://stackoverflow.com

Comment: actually, it might even be suited for [serverfault](http://serverfault.com/)

Comment: Is it `svn update /home/tester` or `svn update /var/www/tester` in the post commit hook? Also shouldn't **/var/www/tester** belong to **apache**?